# CreatedAtAction returns "No route matches the supplied values" 500 error in Asp.Ner Core 3.1 with Api Versioning

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I have an Web API project in Asp.Net Core 3.1 with Api Versioning, with the following setup:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
public abstract class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
{
    ...
}
```

controller that I am testing:

```
public class RegistrationController : BaseApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id}")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<RegistrationDTO>> GetRegistration(int id)
    {
        ...
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create(RegistrationCreateDTO item, ApiVersion apiVersion)
    {
        ...
        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetRegistration), new { id = itemId, version = $"{apiVersion.MajorVersion.Value}" }, itemId);
    }
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work unless I remove [Route{"id"}] and change [HttpGet] to [HttpGet{"id"}]. Any idea what causes this behaviour?

Note that I don't have any specific routes in setup, just a simple `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` and `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers();  });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo worked:
Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddApiVersioning(o =>
            {
                o.ReportApiVersions = true;
                o.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true;
                o.DefaultApiVersion = new ApiVersion(1, 0);
            });
        }


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
        }
```

BaseApiController:

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("api/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]
    public class BaseApiController : ControllerBase
    {
        
    }
```

RegistrationController :

```
public class RegistrationController : BaseApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("{id}")]
        public JsonResult GetRegistration(int id)
        {
            return new JsonResult("aa");
        }
    
    }
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for thorough answer :) There is no difference in this setup and the one that I have (aside that I have a ton of other stuff) but since it is working I will mark it as accepted. 
Side note: file name next to RegistrationController.cs is epic ;)